ERRORED message while doing transact in the chainlink GUI job run, and no value after calling CurrentPrice
actually im new to this, im trying to learn from the documentation. so in the fulfilling request page im doing exactly what it was told there( https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/fulfilling-requests) im getting ERRORED message.
when i did the transact in my runs of my chainlink GUI it is showing ERRORED ERRORED msg in GUI. that means if i did the transact it should retrive the data from this right "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD". but when i called the CurrentPrice function as shown in the docs im getting 0 as valueshowing 0. and also this is the log for my call log for the call. so can anyone help what am i doing wrong here?

Based on your description and error information from Chainlink Node GUI, your Chainlink node can receive the request from the consumer contract and fetch message successfully from "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD".
The whole process failed at the step "submit" which means the node cannot submit the result back to the Operator smart contract. The possible reasons are:

The node address is not added to the whitelist of Operator
You do not have enough balance of native tokens in your node address.

Please check these 2 possible reasons.
Instead of fetching a result through Chainlink Node, Chainlink also provides a product called Chainlink functions. With functions, you do not need to care about configurations of chainlink nodes and operator contracts. You only need to use functions router to send your request from the consumer contract and get the result back.
In this way, the result from off-chain API returned to the consumer contract in a decentralized manner.
Hope it helps.
